# I am developing java application on Netbeans 12.0 with jdk 11 i am facing a problem when i try to install Jasper Plugin it shows me error like this

Tags: jasper-plugin

Some plugins require plugin org.jdesktop.layout to be installed.
The plugin org.jdesktop.layout is requested in version 1.4.  The following plugin is affected:       ireport-designer
Some plugins require plugin org.jdesktop.layout to be installed.
The plugin org.jdesktop.layout is requested in version 1.4.1.  The following plugins are affected:       jasperreports-components       jasperreports-extensions       jasperserver-plugin

Comment: Install the plugin at this address. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66562756/i-am-developing-java-application-on-netbeans-12-0-with-jdk-11-i-am-facing-a-prob/70482832#70482832

Answer (score 0):

You need that plugin .nbm to install the plugins packtet of JaspersReports http://netbeans.apidesign.org/nexus/content/groups/netbeans/org/netbeans/api/org-jdesktop-layout/RELEASE65/